# Could connecting two seperate routers via an ethernet switch cause issues on one or either of the networks?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

We've got 2 incoming internet connections each coming into their own modem / router combi. (I do plan to eventually combine these connections using a load balance, but haven't got round to it yet).

Ive then connected each of these modem / routers to an ethernet switch and a printer to the ethernet switch. Ive done this so that users of both the routers (either connecting via ethernet or wifi) can access the printer. (I dont need the 2 networks to be able to talk to each other, although if this happened with no downsides it would be an added benefit)

My only concern is that there might be an issue caused by the 2 routers talking to each other via the switch - I haven't noticed anything so far, but could this cause an issue or cause the system to stall ? The switch is unmanaged, i guess if there are issues i could resolve this with settings in an unmanaged switch.

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding the ip setup of these 2 routers :

Each modem / router combi has its own incoming DSL, these are 2 separate connections from two different service providers. One of the connections has a dedicated IP, the other has a dynamic IP.

Comment: Are they both passing out IP addresses? On different subnets?

Comment: @mikeazo please see updated question

Comment: But how are IPs handed out on the internal side? That is what I meant. Are both routers running a DHCP server? That would surely cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide feedback without more clarity, do you know the model of your modem/router? Can you give us what your IP range, subnet is set at?

I'm not sure about this, but... help me out gurus:
The router on network 1 is handing out addresses from 192.168.1.1 though 192.168.1.254? Make sure router on network 2 is using 192.168.2.1 through 192.168.2.254. Set your subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 and give your printer a static ip of say 192.168.3.1, subnet 255.255.0.0.

It might need to be more complicated by setting up static routes in your modems to bridge the networks.